# How to create call option function in iOS app using swift language

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to iOS app development and I am using swift language , I am stuck at adding call options when you click button. Please help me by defining your code.

Comment: can you show ur code

Comment: try find a video tutorial on the basics...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your number and execute the code

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)") {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```